# C webserver header sending

Tags: c, sockets, header

I wrote a simple web server in C that listens for a connection and send some text over a socket.
I want **my server to be accessed by a server**. In this case I should s**end headers such as CODE(200), Content type, Content length**.

- How these headers can be sent to the client(browser or telnet)?
- How headers of request can be extracted?

Comment: Now that is a pretty wide question. Headers are lines of text. Parse/format accordingly...? Google for a spec of the HTTP protocol, and go from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Maybe, I just don't understand the question, vote me down.)

The http response header format is not too difficult:

```
header1\n 
header2\n 
<empty line>\n
content\n 
content\n
```

That's all. The webserver should send the headers, an empty line, then the content.

If you wanna test header sending, you should check it with a browser. Add a line to your webserver to send the following header:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=download_me.txt
```

So when you connect to your webserver with a browser, it will pop up a "save as" dialog instead of displaying the downloaded web page in the browser window. If you got the dialog, and the downloaded file is also OK, your webserver sends the headers properly.

G
It's another issue, wether the client handles them as you (and W3C) expect...

*Edit:* HTTP ok status is:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n
```

Google for more status codes.

Comment: You @ern0 are right for a certain amount. To be precise what I wanted is to know how to send these headers to the browser. Is it just writing them to the socket as fallow?
//new_fd is the socket file descripter
'
send(new_fd, "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\n", 16, 0);
   send(new_fd, "Content-Type: text/html\n", 24, 0);
   send(new_fd, "Content-Length: 29\n", 20, 0);
   send(new_fd, "content of the file\n", 10, 0);

'

Comment: Yep, that's all, there isn't any magic, just the empty line. As I said, try it with a browser. Content-lenght isn't mandatory.